# Python Files Type

Tags: python

Please, does anybody knows a function() on Python that reads a file opened with open() function, then returns the filetype of the file?

For example: ASCII TEXT, .TAR FILE, .ZIP FILE, LONG TEXT FILE, etc.

I can do this using POPEN from subprocess module and invoking the Linux's "file" program.

But i need to do this using a Python function, because the script will run on Windows and Linux.

Does anybody knows a solution?

Tks a lot !

Answer (score 5):

See the following code :

```
python -c 'import mimetypes; print(mimetypes.guess_type("/tmp/l.py", strict=True))'
('text/x-python', None)
```

Answer (score 2):

try the [mimetypes](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html) module.

The mimetypes module converts between a filename or URL and the MIME type associated with the filename extension. Conversions are provided from filename to MIME type and from MIME type to filename extension.

Comment: I think the question is more about identifying the type by contents rather than filename.

Comment: Yes. is like Mark said. I need to identify the type of the file, independently of the file extension. So, i need to identify that, even if the file does not have a extension.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not examine the extension beforehand, prior to opening?  The problem with any such approach is that there will be different ways of determining each type of file.  For instance, a gzip'd file may or may not have headers.  Without the headers you would have no real way to know whether the file is gzip'd except to try to decompress it.  I think you would have to have several sub-methods, each of which know how to look for a specific file type.  For instance,

```
is_jpeg()
is_tar()
is_gzip()
is_zip()
is_plain()
is_gif
is_fill_in_the_blank()
```

and then a call to

```
get_filetype(fd):
    if is_jpeg(fd):
        return "jpg"
    elif is_tar(fd):
        return "tar"
    """ etc """
```

Examples:

```
def is_png(fd):
    return fd[:4] == '\x89PNG'

def is_jpeg(fd):
    return fd[:3] == '\xFF\xD8\xFF'

def is_tar(fd):
    """examine header bytes, or just try to do it"""
    # check if timestamp is valid
    fd[136:147] == 'a valid timestamp'
    fd[156:157] in ('0', '1', '2')
    # etc

    from tarfile import TarFile, TarError
    from StringIO import StringIO
    io = StringIO(fd)
    try:
        tf = TarFile(fileobj=io)
        return True
    except TarError:
        return False

def is_gzip(fd):
    import zlib
    from StringIO import StringIO
    io = StringIO(fd)
    for i in range(-15, 16):
        try:
            dec = zlib.uncompress(io, i)
            return True
        except:
            pass
    return False
```

You can reference the specific header byte locations and write formulas for those:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)
http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gif
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format)

Comment: Hi. I can make these 2 approaches. I can examine about the file extension, and the file type. But, only looking by the extension will not give me the real information that i need. The user can change the file extension, for example.

Comment: If you really need to know the type from the open file, then this is really the only approach I can think of.  Do you have a limited number of file types you need to be able to check for?

Comment: Yes sberry, on the reality i just need to check for an one type of file, all the others types i will reject !

Comment: Sorry sberry, i was out for a little and returning just now...
So, i need to identify a text file, which the FILE' s Linux command tool identifies like a "BIG TEXT FILE". It is a giant text file from a report tool.

Answer (score 1):

[os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) Are you just looking for the extension.

use splitext(path)

Comment: Hi. I need to identify the type of the file, independently of the file extension. So, i need to identify that, even if the file does not have a extension.

Answer (score 0):

Just install "File for Windows": http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm - download "Complete package, except sources". Do not forget to change your "file" path from /usr/bin/file to your installation, e.g. C:/"Program Files (x86)"/GnuWin32/bin/file

I've used this for a Django project based on Debian and implemented it on Windows, just to check if this would work (which it did, after some hassle :-) ).